# Platform that disappears and reappears when you jump doesn't work.

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm making a 2D Platformer and I have a block that I want to disappear when you jump and then reappear when you jump again. However, the block is just staying shown and I don't why. Here is my script;

```
var animator : Animator;
animator.SetBool("changeState", false);
var AudioOut : AudioSource;

var showNext = true;


function Update (){
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") & showNext == true){
        Close();
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") & showNext == false){
        Open();
    }
}

function Close(){
    GetComponent.<AudioSource>().Play();
    animator.SetBool("changeState", true);
    showNext = false;
}

function Open(){
        AudioOut.GetComponent.<AudioSource>().Play();
        animator.SetBool("changeState", false);
        showNext = true;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: do you get any runtime erros in the console ? Maybe your animator is not being in the correct state from the begging. Try calling animator.SetBool("changeState",false) in the Start method.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

This line:

```
animator.SetBool("changeState", false);
```

written on the top of your script and doesn't lies inside any function. Probably wrap it inside `Start` function. Verify that you are passing correct value to `changeState` state. For `true` value it should behave as `Close`. Verify from `Animation` tab and `Animator` tab.

Comment: I've removed that line because i don't really know why I put it in there. I've double checked everything in the script and the animator and it all seems to be in check.

Comment: Have you attached this script to game object and is enabled?

Answer (score -1):

this might help

there is another way you can achieve this

show the platform if the collosionEnter is triggered and on collision exit disappear the plaform

Comment: I don't think its the conditions of when to disappear the platform that's the problem, he is having trouble with the mechanics of actually disappearing the platform